# How to enable proxy protocol in javalin?

Tags: java, proxy, load-balancing, javalin, proxy-protocol

I bought a load balancer at hetzner and for my backend (written in Java, Web-Server is Javalin) I want to use the Proxy Protocol, that the IP-Adresses will be redirected to my web-services.

[Hetzner Load Balancer enable Proxy Protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9buW.png)
Hetzner says, that my service must support this. They also linked an how-to for nginx: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/

At the moment, my services aren't reachable through the load balancer if I enable the proxy protocol:
Bad Message 400
reason: Illegal character SPACE=' '

Does anyone know, how to do this for Javalin?
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Javalin does not support the Proxy Protocol.

If you are proxying your traffic through Nginx, you don't need to use the proxy protocol in Javalin, since it will be the final destination. Nginx will handle the proxy protocol and forward the request to Javalin. [You can then use the X-Forwarded-For header to get the original IP address.](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/)